# Angular.js updating ng-class when long polling changes a watched value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Using angular.js

I am long polling a server, and want to update an element in view, with a class of 'updated', whenever a `build_tag` value has been incremented.

So I'm struggling, trying to find an elegant way to add an updated class, when `catalog.products[??].build_tag` has been changed.

```
<div ng-controller="MyAwesomeController as env">
    <div class="product-wrapper" ng-class="{'error': product.error, 'updated': HELP!! }" ng-repeat="product in env.catalog">

    <!-- show stuff in cool and interesting ways -->
```

EnvironmentController:

```
app.controller('EnvironmentController', ['$http', '$interval', function($http, $interval) {

    var vm = this;
    var pollingInterval = 5000;
    vm.catalog = {

        // only showing 2 products for the
        // sake of brevity. I normally have dozens
        // of products
        products: [{
            name: 'widget1',
            error: false,
            build_tag: 7
        }, {
            name: 'widget2',
            error: false,
            build_tag: 5
        }]
    };

    function fetchData() {
        $http.get('/builds.json').then(function (resolved) {
            if (resolved.status === 200) {
                vm.catalog = angular.merge(vm.catalog, resolved.data);
            }
        }, function (rejected) {
            ... do error stuff
        });
    }

    $interval(fetchData, pollingInterval);
... more controller stuff
```

Does that make sense? When I poll the server, I update `vm.config`. I expect each product-wrapper to watch it's `build_tag`. And I want to add an `updated` class to the respective element in the view if the `build_tag` has changed.

Comment: what is `vm.config` for? It's not shown in view and not previously defined. Also probably don't want to reassign it when use extend

Comment: whoops - sorry. That was a typo. `vm.config` should be `vm.catalog`. Updated it.

Comment: can create a prototype model for each product with an `update` method that compares old values... or loop through each and compare and add an `updated` property

Comment: also no need to reassign when doing extend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write a directive to add the class.

```
.directive('buildTagUpdated', [function() {
    return {
        link: function buildTagUpdatedLink(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$watch('buildTag', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    /**
                     * you can use element methods here 
                     * see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element
                     */
                }
            });
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            buildTag: '='
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then on the element you want to update, just add the `build-tag-updated="product.build_tag"`